# How to change the size of an object, when it hits a border?

Tags: java, processing

I wanted to code an object, which has a pulsating effect when hitting the edge of the program while moving. So the object should get a little bigger, when hitting the edge and then go to the output size over and over again. I've searched hours for my problem, but couldn't find an answer. Any tips?

My code:

```
float ballsizeX = 60;
float ballsizeY = 60;
float ballX = 0;
float ballY = 0;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 2;

void setup() {   
    size(500, 400);
}

void draw() {   
    background(255);   
    fill(random(255), 255, random(255));   
    ellipse(ballX, ballY, ballsizeX, ballsizeY);   
    speedX = speedX * 1;   
    speedY = speedY * 1;   
    ballX = ballX + speedX;   
    ballY = ballY + speedY;

    if (ballX < 0 || ballX > 500) {     
        speedX = speedX * (-1);
    } else if (ballY < 0 || ballY > 400) {     
        speedY = speedY * (-1);     
    }
    else if(ballsizeX>60||ballsizeY>60){
        ballsizeX = ballsizeX * (-1);
        ballsizeY = ballsizeY * (-1);
    }
    else if(ballsizeX<30||ballsizeY<30){
        ballsizeX = ballsizeX + 1;
        ballsizeY = ballsizeY + 1;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the initial state, `ballsizeX` is 60 and `ballsizeY` is.

Neither the condition `ballsizeX>60||ballsizeY>60` is fulfilled, nor the condition `ballsizeX<30||ballsizeY<30` is fulfilled.
Since both values are never changed (except in the code block covered by the conditions), the conditions will be never fulfilled.

Increment the size of the ball, if it hits a wall:

```py
 if (ballX < 0 || ballX > 500) {     
    speedX = speedX * (-1);  
    ballsizeY = initSize*2;
 } else if (ballY < 0 || ballY > 400) {     
    speedY = speedY * (-1);
    ballsizeX = initSize*2;
 }
```

Reduce the size of the ball in every frame as long it is grater than the initial size:

```py
if ( ballsizeX > 30 ) {
     ballsizeX = ballsizeX - 1;
}
if ( ballsizeY > 30 ) {
     ballsizeY = ballsizeY - 1;
}
```

See the example, where I applied the suggestions to your original code:

[image]

```py
float initSize = 30;
float ballsizeX = initSize;
float ballsizeY = initSize;
float ballX = initSize/2;
float ballY = initSize/2;
float speedX = 2;
float speedY = 2;

void setup() {   
    size(500, 400);
}
void draw() {   
    background(255);   
    fill(random(255), 255, random(255));   
    ellipse(ballX, ballY, ballsizeX, ballsizeY);   
    speedX = speedX * 1;   
    speedY = speedY * 1;   
    ballX = ballX + speedX;   
    ballY = ballY + speedY;

    if ( ballsizeX > initSize ) {
         ballsizeX = ballsizeX - 1;
    }
    if ( ballsizeY > initSize ) {
         ballsizeY = ballsizeY - 1;
    }  

    if (ballX < initSize/2 || ballX > width-initSize/2) {     
        speedX = speedX * (-1);  
        ballsizeY = 60;
     } else if (ballY < initSize/2 || ballY > height-initSize/2) {     
        speedY = speedY * (-1);
        ballsizeX = 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the dependence is the initial size, which is the variable value between 30 and 60, always changing. You also made the ball moving inside the program (not like mine, which moved a little outward). Thanks for the help, I think I understand my mistakes now.